# Batch - Variable giving different outputs at ECHO and IF

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, echo

I am currently implementing a postprocess in batch, and after some changes a few code snipplets simply don't work anymore....

What I am trying to do:

```
@echo off & setlocal
ECHO %netUse%                        //For debugging!
IF NOT "%netUse%" == "" (            //Double checking if Variable is set
    IF %netUse% EQU 1 (
        IF %netUsePW% EQU 1 (
            NET USE %netUseLetter% %netPath% %pw% /user:%netUser% 
        )
        IF %netUsePW% EQU 0 (
            NET USE %netUseLetter% %netPath%
        )
    )
)
```

When I run that code, this is the output:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\ID GmbH\PRODETTE\DAX\ISDN>ECHO 0
0   <--- That's right! It is set to ZERO via a "configuration" Batch
"1" kann syntaktisch an dieser Stelle nicht verarbeitet werden.   <-- ???

C:\Program Files (x86)\ID GmbH\PRODETTE\DAX\ISDN>               IF  EQU 1 (  <-- Why isn't it comparing the variable?
```

And just for completionists sake, I am loading all of these variables form another batch file, "Settings.bat"
I am running that file via
    CALL :postCopySettings.bat

contents:

```
SET netUse=0
SET netUsePW=
SET netUseLetter=
SET netPath=
SET netUser=
SET pw=
SET configLoaded=1
```

(Since netUse is 0, I don't need to populate the other variables... right?)

TL:DR: Batch doesn't work, but I don't know why.

Comment: Variable `NetUsePW` is empty...

Comment: Hmm. Do I need to set %netUsePW% even when %netUse% is set to 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that variable `netUsePW` is not set.

When `netUse` is set to `0`, and `netUsePW`, `netUseLetter`, `netUsePath`, `pw` are all empty, your code...:

```dos
@echo off & setlocal
ECHO %netUse%
IF NOT "%netUse%" == "" (
    IF %netUse% EQU 1 (
        IF %netUsePW% EQU 1 (
            NET USE %netUseLetter% %netPath% %pw% /user:%netUser%
        )
        IF %netUsePW% EQU 0 (
            NET USE %netUseLetter% %netPath%
        )
    )
)
```

...expands to...:

```dos
@echo off & setlocal
ECHO 0
IF NOT "0" == "" (
    IF 0 EQU 1 (
        IF  EQU 1 (
            NET USE    /user:0
        )
        IF  EQU 0 (
            NET USE  
        )
    )
)
```

As you can see, there are two syntax issues, which cause the error:

> ```dos
> IF  EQU 1
> IF  EQU 0
> ```

Although `netUse` is set to `0` and you therefore expect the statements after `IF %netUse% EQU 1` not to be executed, they are still parsed, because the entire code block is parsed before any commands are executed.

---

To overcome this, there are several ways:

1. Preset variables with non-empty values:

   ```dos
   @echo off & setlocal
   ECHO %netUse%
   IF "%netUse%" == "" (set "netUse=-1" & set "setUsePW=-1")
   IF NOT "%netUse%" == "" (
       IF %netUse% EQU 1 (
           IF %netUsePW% EQU 1 (
               NET USE %netUseLetter% %netPath% %pw% /user:%netUser%
           )
           IF %netUsePW% EQU 0 (
               NET USE %netUseLetter% %netPath%
           )
       )
   )
   ```
2. Avoid code blocks by changing the logic a bit and using `goto`:

   ```dos
   @echo off & setlocal
   ECHO %netUse%
   IF "%netUse%" == "" goto :SKIP
   IF %netUse% NEQ 1 goto :SKIP
   IF %netUsePW% EQU 1 (
       NET USE %netUseLetter% %netPath% %pw% /user:%netUser%
   )
   IF %netUsePW% EQU 0 (
       NET USE %netUseLetter% %netPath%
   )
   :SKIP
   ```
3. Avoid code blocks by moving some code into subroutines and using `call` to call them:

   ```dos
   @echo off & setlocal
   ECHO %netUse%
   IF NOT "%netUse%" == "" call :TEST "%netUse%" "%netUsePW%" "%netUseLetter%" "%netPath%" "%pw%"
   exit /B

   :TEST
   IF %~1 EQU 1 call :TESTPW "%~1" "%~2" "%~3" "%~4" "%~5"
   exit /B

   :TESTPW
   IF %~2 EQU 1 (
       NET USE %~3 %~4 %~5 /user:%~1
   )
   IF %~2 EQU 0 (
       NET USE %~3 %~4
   )
   exit /B
   ```
4. Enable and apply [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) to do the variable expansion during execution rather than while parsing:

   ```dos
   @echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   ECHO %netUse%
   IF NOT "%netUse%" == "" (
       IF !netUse! EQU 1 (
           IF !netUsePW! EQU 1 (
               NET USE %netUseLetter% %netPath% %pw% /user:!netUser!
           )
           IF !netUsePW! EQU 0 (
               NET USE %netUseLetter% %netPath%
           )
       )
   )
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF NOT "%netUse%" == "" (            //Double checking if Variable is set
    IF %netUse% EQU 1 (
        IF %netUsePW% EQU 1 (
```

No point in testing "netuse" then complaining that "netusePW" is not set.

Comment: Hmm. Do I need to set %netUsePW% even when %netUse% is set to 0?

Comment: Yes - and no. Batch replaces any `%var% with its then-current value, then executes the result. If `netusepw` is undefined, it's replaced by *nothing*, so will yield a syntax-error with the construct you have. Changing the `if` to `IF "%netUsePW%" EQU "1"` will ensure that there is a non-empty string on both sides of the comparison operator, so the syntax wiill be valid. In that case, if `netusepw` is empty, batch sees `IF "" EQU "1"` which is syntactically valid and is resolved to `false`.